# How to get Spring boot project work with JPMS?

Tags: java, spring, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to set up a modular spring application. I have a very basic one, generated by start.spring.io. Only thing I did is added `module-info.java` file, which looks like this:

```
open module modules {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.context;
}
```

It compiles, shows no errors in IntelliJ. When I run it it throws exceptions. Console looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:447) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:268) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:147) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.7.5/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.7.5/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.7.5/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.7.5/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.7.5/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:na]
    at modules@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.example.modules.ModulesApplication.main(ModulesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.example.modules.ModulesApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91c2c32e (in module modules) cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x3bd40a57) because module modules does not read unnamed module @0x3bd40a57
    at modules@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.example.modules.ModulesApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91c2c32e.CGLIB$STATICHOOK1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at modules@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.example.modules.ModulesApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91c2c32e.<clinit>(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:602) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I can't figure out which more modules should I require. I've tried adding some JVM arguments but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Modules (JPMS) do not allow the use of reflection without opening the appropriate package to the module using reflection.

The "Caused by:" line in the stack trace shows the illegal access:

> class com.example.modules.ModulesApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91c2c32e (in module modules) cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x3bd40a57) because module modules does not read unnamed module @0x3bd40a57

Since the package `org.springframework.cglib.core` does not have a module descriptor it is in the "unnamed module" which is not "open" to reflection.

You can fix this by adding the following VM argument (either on the command line or your IDE's run configuration) to allow the `modules` module to read the unnamed module:

```bash
--add-reads modules=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: This hack shouldn’t be necessary 5 years after Java 9 came out. I’m wondering if the omission is deliberate.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar the intention to get rid of reflection is deliberate.

Comment: Spring lives on reflection, so, getting rid of reflection won’t work for them. What I meant was why didn’t they include a module file enabling reflection? My guess is, like many other libraries, they chose to not modularize their jars because they saw no benefit in doing so. JPMS is a failed experiment.

Comment: Spring/CGLib could simply add a `InjectedClass.class.getModule().addReads(SomeSpringClass.class.getModule())` into the generated classes initializer, which would fix that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the wonderful thing about Open Source software is that anyone can contribute a fix!   Have you considered submitting a PR to make that change and  help avoid issues like the OP here?  You'd help many people!

Comment: @DanielWiddis in theory. In practice, I would have to setup a development environment to build & run the tests for spring, write up some PR as to why that change is important, write tests for the change... Too much hassle for something I don't even use. But feel free to use my idea and submit a PR yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to run a sample Spring Boot application with Java Modules using latest version.

The `module-info.java` file looks like:

```java
module spring.jpms {
  requires spring.core;
  requires spring.boot;
  requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
  requires spring.context;
  requires spring.beans;

  opens org.example to
      spring.core,
      spring.beans,
      spring.context;
}
```

When I run the application I include all the spring .jar files in the java launcher's module-path.

Here is a complete example of a Spring Boot application that runs with Java Modules:
https://github.com/agavrilov76/spring-jpms